# How to throw errors in a try / catch block inside an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my function:

```
async function doRequest() {
  try {
    const response = await doAsyncOperation();
    if (response.isError) {
      throw new Error(response.isError);
    }
    return 'All good';
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return 'Error happened';
  }
}
```

Here I try to check if there was an error in the response, and if it is, throw an error (thereby it should get into catch), and process it already in catch, however, this code leads to an error:

```
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

and the code doesn't reach line 'Error happened'.
What am I doing wrong? And how to do it properly?

Comment: Is this a simplified version of the code? Looks like it should work to me.

Comment: The `throw` statement is fine. Are you sure it is reached, and that error doesn't come from `doAsyncOperation()`?

Comment: It seems you have not posted the entire error message. Would you be able to post everything, and show us line 68?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this: `throw {error: response.isError'}`
or `throw response.isError`
into the try catch block
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

In you specific example:

```
if (response.isError) throw response.isError
```

Comment: so that means that syntax construction "new Error()" was causing the problem. Thx, now it works

Comment: I think so, I know it because I faced the same problem recently on a Express router.

Comment: The catch block will happens only if the promise was rejected. In the case of your excercise It seems like you are receiving a response. On that case the catch block is not being reached.